# 'Assembly is a higher version than referenced assembly' error in SSIS script tasks

Tags: assembly-references, script-task

In my SSIS packages, I've a script task which references the below assemblies...

Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS, Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask

How can i get the same package to work on multiple SQL Server environments (For eg. SQL Server 2014, 2016 etc)?

At the moment, the packages were developed by referring to v12 assemblies. When i run those packages on a SQL 2016 box, I keep getting the below errors..

*Description: CS1705 - Assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' uses 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91', d:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS.dll, 0, 0*

Answer (score 0):

I tried to upgrade my 2008 package to 2016 and had a similar error on my script task. What I did was delete the old reference to  Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll and add a new reference from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS\v4.0_13.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll